# Count Excel cells in a row until the sum is reached?

Tags: excel, sum

I have two rows and want to count the number of cells in the row-2, offset by one column, I need to sum up to reach but not exceed the number in row-1

> **A B C D E F G**
>
> 20 39
>
> 2 3 15 12 8 10
>
> x y

So "x" should be 3 (2+3+15 < 20)
and "y" should be 4 (3+15+12+8 < 39)

I tried all sorts of formulas, but none worked, this one is supposed to work but doesnt:

```
=MATCH(A1,INDEX(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A2,,,,COLUMN(A2:G2))),0))
```

**edit**

The actual Excel had slightly different numbers

> F D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R
>
> 3404    1409    312971  290486  255425  233206  209780  852766  791217  762958  707437  705119 blank 23141
>
> 1135    470 104324  96829   85142   77735   69927   284255  263739  254319  235812  235040  blank 34212

Top row is 44 and the bottom one is 46

The formula I use is :

```
=MATCH(F44,INDEX(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(F46,,,,COLUMN($F$46:$R$46))),0))
```

** Edit 2 **

Also - how can I exclude blank cells in this?

Comment: What does "supposed to work but doesn't" mean?  It worked fine for me with a slight modification, I made the "A2:G2" absolute referenced rather than relative (so: $A$2:$G$2) so the references wouldn't change when I dragged it across.  I got the expected 3 and 4 in cells A3 B3.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and it did work indeed, but when I tried on the actual Excel which has slightly different values it didn't. I will update the question

Comment: that's usually the case...if you don't post data that's causing the problem, there's not a lot people can do to help.

Comment: yes, I realized - just updated the question, can you please take a look?

Comment: your data layout isn't clear. Is it |3404|1409|312971| (meaning 3404 is in cell F, 1409 in cell G, etc.)?

Comment: yes, it's space-delimited, spaces are tabs essentially.

Comment: `=MATCH(F44,INDEX(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(F46,,,,COLUMN($F$46:$R$46)-MIN(COLUMN($F$46:$R$46))+1)),0))` will do overall not skipping blank.